# Does changing the default encryption type used by Access cause compatibility problems when distributing runtime apps?

Tags: encryption, ms-access-2007

If I change the registry setting to make Access 2007 use stronger encryption by default e.g. instead of "*Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0, with RC4 encryption using a 40-bit key*" it uses "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0, with RC4 encryption using a 128-bit key*" and then distribute an Access runtime application that uses this enhanced encryption to other computers, will this break compatibility with those other computers and will they have to also change their registry settings to the same default encryption method?

The is a tool that can do this automatically [here](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Changing-the-encryption-type-in-Access-2007). The site explains more about what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a reply posted to a question on [EverythingAccess.com](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Changing-the-encryption-type-in-Access-2007):

> Once you have applied the encryption to the file, the encryption algorithms are fixed for that file (unless you decrypt and re-apply password/encryption). Provided the chosen encryption provider/algorithm are available on the end user machine, there should be no issues at all.

and to a question about the availability of the encryption algorithms on other machines:

> this document suggests some providers are dependant on individual countries export restrictions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962093.aspx

So it seems that it is safe to change the default encryption used by Access on your machine and distribute the databases if the encryption algorithm is available on the end user's machine, but that the availability is restricted only by USA export restrictions. I have personally investigated this on machines containing Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 in the United Kingdom and I have found both the Microsoft Enhanced and Strong Encryption algorithms present on all.

Further, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms947420.aspx the Strong Encryption algorithm is backward-compatible with the Microsoft Base and Enhanced Encryption algorithm.